# How can I create an unordered map containing a string as key value and pointing to a linked list?

Tags: c++

Is there a way I can create a unordered_map such that it is something like,

```
unordered_map<string,linkedlist>
```

Basically, I will be inputting the key value, and if any string (its sorted value) equals the already stored key value, then I will insert that string in the linkedlist for that sorted value. How do I declare such an unordered_map?

Comment: Um, `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list> foo;`

Comment: If the only point of the linked list is to store multiple occurrences of the key string, you might want to use [`std::multiset<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) or [`std::unordered_multiset<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset) instead.

Comment: I'll try to guess what you want. Given `SomeType<std::string, std::list<std::string>> map;` you want to be able to say `map.insert("Hello");` which inserts as usual. Then you do `map.insert("Hello");` again and the second hello string goes into the list instead. If the comparison function of the map only considers the first 3 characters and you can have multiple non-identical strings in one group this would actually make sense. And you want to know what `SomeType` has to be to make this work. Did I guess right?

Comment: @nwp, I am just trying to make a function for printing all anagrams together. This is one of the methods that I thought of using a hash table. And therefore, I will insert all the elements into the list.

Comment: @NathanOliver, how exactly will insertion happen in the list? What will be the syntax in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<std::string> > data;
```

Although I am having a bit of a hard time understanding what exactly you are trying to accomplish... I am not sure if a map of linked lists is what you will need

Comment: data[key].push_back(var);